# Making pants hang off a body?

Tags: modeling

I've made pants, and I've made a body, and I lined the two up. What I want to do is the following:

- Have the body not be affected by gravity, but still have collision against the pants.
- Have the pants have "elastic waistbands" on the waist and ankles so that the pants stick to the body.
- Have the pants have cloth physics with gravity, so that the body hangs to the body, but also hangs it's excess fabric, creating baggy pants.

How can I do this? :/

[image]

Comment: http://www.blendernation.com/2016/02/25/cloth-sewing-in-blender/

Comment: This tutorial is amazing! However I'm still having a small issue: Sometimes the cloth goes through the mesh of the body in some areas like the ankle. How can I fix this?