# Cloth animation - pants falling down - pin to waist :)

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've just created pants/trousers for a standard human model by selecting the legs area, creating a new object and scaling it up little, then adding cloth modifier (e.g. denim)
When I animate, the pants just 'fall down' obviously - I think the answer is pinning - but not sure how to pin the pants to the original character's waistline (as if the pants had a belt keeping them up?)

And please don't point me to this question

[Making pants hang off a body?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49180/making-pants-hang-off-a-body)

Since it only links to a tutorial which shows how to create a top - not a skirt or pants hanging from a waist.

Thanks
J

Comment: see first answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49190/making-an-elastic-waistband-on-clothing?noredirect=1&lq=1